# STM BlueNRG-MS Max Characteristic length

Tags: c, stm32, bluenrg

My general understanding is that the BLE standard supports characteristics with a lenght of up to 512 bytes. I'm using the BlueNRG-MS chip from STM but there the function call to add a characteristic has a uint8_t value for the length parameter

```
tBleStatus aci_gatt_add_char(uint16_t serviceHandle,
                 uint8_t charUuidType,
                 const uint8_t* charUuid, 
                 uint8_t charValueLen, 
                 uint8_t charProperties,
                 uint8_t secPermissions,
                 uint8_t gattEvtMask,
                 uint8_t encryKeySize,
                 uint8_t isVariable,
                 uint16_t* charHandle);
```

So this would allow only a maximum characteristic length of 255 bytes.
According to [this](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/6d/a1/5b/6c/dc/ab/48/76/DM00162667.pdf/files/DM00162667.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00162667.pdf) document the stack itself supports 2 bytes with FW 7.2 or higher.
I have 7.23 so this should be fine but I cannot find any reference or example of a BlueNRG-MS middleware that would support a call with `charValueLen` of type `uint16_t`. I also downloaded the latest STSW-BLUENRG-DK and the examples also only support `uint8_t charValueLen`.

Comment: You might get a more useful answer in the ST community forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it supports charValueLen with uint16_t too.
Sample function would be as followed:

```
tBleStatus aci_gatt_add_char(uint16_t serviceHandle,
                         uint8_t charUuidType,
                         const uint8_t* charUuid, 
                         uint16_t charValueLen, 
                         uint8_t charProperties,
                         uint8_t secPermissions,
                         uint8_t gattEvtMask,
                         uint8_t encryKeySize,
                         uint8_t isVariable,
                         uint16_t* charHandle)
{
  struct hci_request rq;
  gatt_add_serv_rp resp;
  uint8_t buffer[26];
  ... // code omitted w/o needing modification

  Osal_MemCpy(buffer + indx, charUuid, uuid_len);
  indx +=  uuid_len;

  charValueLen = htobs(charValueLen);
  Osal_MemCpy(buffer + indx, &charValueLen, 2);
  indx += 2;

  buffer[indx] = charProperties;
  indx++;
  ... // code omitted w/o needing modification
}
```